# passing two dimension array to class member function

Tags: c++, arrays

I was hoping someone can give me an idea of how to send two arrays- probably as an object -- I have to a class member function and then add the elements of an array and set the total equal to totsales ..
I am dealing with quarterly sales totals for each division. I think i'm close but having some trouble. My goal outcome is totalsales for  all division in a lump but just utilizing classes to achieve this.

Any insight would be much appreciated!

(excuse any typos or formatting as I am still very new at c++)

```
class Corpsales
{
private:

static double totSales;


public:
Corpsales()

{

    totSales = 0;

}

void calcQrtSales (Corpsales qrtsalesarray[])
{


totSales += qrtsalesarray[div][qtr];

}

double showTotSales ()

{  
    return  totSales;
}

}

const int SALES_DIV = 6;
const int SALES_QRT = 4;
double qrtSales;
int  divs;

int main (){


Corpsales divsales[SALES_DIV][SALES_QRT];

cout<< "Please enter Sales for 6 Divisions: " << endl;

for (int div = 0 ; div < SALES_DIV ; div++)
{

    for ( int qrt = 0 ; qrt < SALES_QRT ; qrt ++) 


    {
cout <<  " Division " << (div+1 ) << " -> Quarter " << (qrt +1) <<          ":";
      cin >> divsales[div][qrt];
    //here is my issue i think-->>>   //divsales[qrt].calcQrtSales(qrtSales);
    }


}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you should indent the code inside of your class for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a two-dimensional array as a parameter:

```
void calcQrtSales (Corpsales[][] qrtsalesarray)
{
    totSales += qrtsalesarray[div][qtr];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass a static 2D array. For compatibility, the size is defined in macros not const int.

```
#define SALES_DIV 6
#define SALES_QRT 4

void calcQrtSales (Corpsales (qrtsalesarray)[SALES_DIV][SALES_QRT] )
{
    totSales += qrtsalesarray[div][qtr];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond egur , I appreciate. I will try both to see if they work for me!

Answer (score 0):

so this part looks fine then ?

```
    cout <<  " Division " << (div+1 ) << " -> Quarter " << (qrt +1) << ":";
    cin >> divsales[div][qrt];

   <b>here is my issue i think-->>> </b>          divsales[qrt].calcQrtSales(qrtSales);
  }
```